# jenkins: rebuild main repository with the latest commit from submodule when submodule is updated

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

could you please help me with workflow in jenkins. we have main repository rep1 with submodule s1. submodule has been added to rep1 with specific commit number. we frequently commit to s1. but jenkins doesn't see new changes when updating rep1 because s1 has old commit number.

how can we configure jenkins to automatically rebuild rep1 with the latest changes from s1 when s1 is updated by other developers?

Comment: maybe we should use subtrees instead of modules? does anybody have experience with jenkins and git subtrees?

Answer (score 0):

When you commit s1, you need to make sure you update your pointer to the proper commit hash in r1 and push, otherwise r1 is still pointing to the old version of s1.

Example:

```
~/r1 <---- main project
~/r1/s1 <---- submodule in your project
```

< make changes to s1 >

```
# you commit your changes for whatever
~/r1/s1: git commit -am 'major commit not doing single adds'
```

Now, switch back to ~/r1

```
~/r1: git add ./s1
~/r1: git commit -m 'updating pointer for submodule in changes in s1'
```

Now when you push your changes, jenkins will see you are telling it you updated your pointer in the main repository and you need to do a full new rebuild (assuming jenkins will do a rebuild for any updates on r1).

Comment: unfortunately it requires manual update in r1 after each commit to s1. it's unacceptable.

Comment: You could always write some sort of after git commit hook that would automatically do the functionality above, but as far as submodules are concerned, that is how you notify the main repository that an update has occurred.  You might be able to setup something in Jenkins to look at both the main and submodule repositories, but that would take a little digging.

Comment: who knows how to configure getting the fresh git sources from all submodules in jenkins? should we use some plugins or jobs there?

Comment: You could have a script kick off in your build to do a 'git submodule update' in the root of your project.  Or have it as part of your build commands.